# Create PDF of Images in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my Django Application I am creating Barcodes of an Object and up until then it works fine, the `PNGs` are created perfectly but How can I arrange them in a PDF in a 7x2 Grid such that they can be printed?

Is there any Library which takes the images as input and create a pdf with these images?

Here's the code:

```
class GrnBarcodes(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        grn = Grn.objects.filter(pk=pk)[0]
        grn_prod = grn.items.all()
        items = []
        for i in grn_prod:
            for j in range(i.item_quantity):
                items.append("YNT9299"+str(pk)+str(i.item.short_code)+str(j+1))

        zpl_img = []
        for i in items:
            barcode = get_barcode(value=i, width=650)
            a = barcode.save(formats=['PNG'], fnRoot=str(i))
            with open(a, 'rb') as image:
                img = image.read()
                grf = GRF.from_image(img, 'YNT')
            grf.optimise_barcodes()
            # os.remove(a)
            zpl_img.append(grf.to_zpl())


        return Response(zpl_img)
```

The grid that I have to place these images looks like this:

[image]

Drive Link to images:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YDdmiePc3qQ0DW_UZFigNClCPs89ITGz?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have another solution. Make an HTML page and then print it as you like. You can set page width and height as inches or centimeter exact as your paper. Also, you can choose your cell width exactly. I have for now given cell width of 50% and 7 rows evenly spaced, you can make it exactly as you like. CSS3 `@media print` will also help you with this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Barcode Print</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .grid-container {
            width: 21cm;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .page {
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
            padding-top: 1.5362cm;
            padding-bottom: 1.5362cm;
            padding-left: 0.5122cm;
            padding-right: 0.5122cm;
        }

        .grid-row {
            display: flex;
        }

        .grid-col {
            margin-left: 0.0854cm;
            margin-right: 0.0854cm;
            width: 9.9024cm;
            height: 3.7552cm;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #eee;
        }

        img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="grid-container">
    {% for page in imglist %}
    <div class="page">
        {% for row in page %}
        <div class="grid-row">
            {% for col in row %}
            <div class="grid-col">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ col }}" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use this in Django templates and for the image, you can use Base64 images you are not saving barcodes to any storage.

Answer (score 2):

No need to look too far, the standard [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library does it quite well.

Here is some code that will do it, that was a nice exercise:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor
from typing import List


def gen_flow_layout(w: int, h: int, images: List[Image.Image], color="white", mx=5, my=5) -> List[Image.Image]:
    """ Generate a sequence of images arranged in flow layout on pages of given size, from input images list
        Args:
            w: Output pdf page width in pixels
            h: Output pdf page height in pixels
            images: List of imput images
            mx: Horizontal margin between images in pixels
            my: Vertical margin between images in pixels
        Return:
            List of image objects, each one representing a single page in PDF.
    """

    # Basic input validation
    if any(im for im in images if im.width > mx + w or im.height > my + h):
        raise ValueError("Input images are too large")

    # Create the firs page
    output = [] # We will put all generated pages here
    out_im = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(w, h), color="white")
    x = mx
    y = my
    rowh = 0
    while images:
        # Parse input images one by one
        im = images.pop(0)

        # Check if we have enough space to paste image in current row
        if w - x < im.width:  # Start a new row
        y += rowh + my
        x = mx
        rowh = 0

        # Check if we need to open a new page
        if h - y < im.height:  # Need to start a new page
            output.append(out_im)
            out_im = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(w, h), color="white")
            x = mx
            y = my

        # Now actually put the image on the page
        out_im.paste(im, (x, y))

        x += mx + im.width
        rowh = max(rowh, im.height)

    if out_im:  # Handle the last partially full page
        output.append(out_im)

    return output


def gen_flow_layout_pdf(file_name: str, w: int, h: int, images: List[Image.Image], color="white", mx=5, my=5, **kwargs) -> List[Image.Image]:
    """ Generate a sequence of images arranged in flow layout on pages of given size, from input images list,
        and save as PDF
        Args:
            file_name: Output pdf file name
            w: Output pdf page width in pixels
            h: Output pdf page height in pixels
            images: List of imput images
            mx: Horizontal margin between images in pixels
            my: Vertical margin between images in pixels
            **kwargs: Additional arguments to be passed directly to PIL.Image.save
    """
    pages = gen_flow_layout(w, h, images, color, mx, my)
    pages[0].save(file_name, format="PDF", save_all=True, append_images=pages[1:], **kwargs)
```

This is how you use it:

```
# Play around with w, h and resolution (dpi) parameters to get the image
# size you want. In this example I load input images from file, don't know
# exactly how you generated your barcodes, but chances are you don't have
# to save them as files but convert them to PIL images directly.
gen_flow_layout_pdf("example.pdf", 1300, 1300, [Image.open("img1.jpg"), Image.open("img2.png"), some_other_image], resolution=150)
```

**EDIT:**

For your specific case. You need grid 7x2 on print page. Standard A4 page is 210x297mm. You barcode is 600x101px. You can make the grid horizontal or vertical (horizontal looks better considereing your image size, but do what you want).

Lets start with horizontal laout. We need to place 2 images inside 297 mm page. This means page width should be around 1290-1300px to look good. What should be the DPI for 297mm to turn into 1300px? It is a simple calculation, 1 pixel/mm = 25.4 dpi, but I prefer to use [calculator](https://www.pixelcalculator.com/?round=&FORM=1&DP=1&FA=&lang=en&mm1=297&mm2=210&dpi1=111&sub1=%20calculate%20#a1).

It turns out, on dpi 111 we get width 1298px which seems good enough. The page height should be, according to the same calculation, 918px.

```
gen_flow_layout_pdf("1.pdf", 1298, 918, images,  resolution=111)
```

This is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/byyx7hb63moml8i/1.pdf?dl=0

Not good, we wanted 7x2 but this is 8x2. Lets play around with `my` argument to get some vertical spacing between images. Can also adjust mx too look better. So some trial and erro and this looks pretty good:

```
gen_flow_layout_pdf("2.pdf", 1298, 918, images, mx = 30, my=25, resolution=111)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vg7woqh9glmjobh/2.pdf?dl=0

As I said horizontal layout looks better, but what if you want vertical layout? Well, same. Now page is 210x297mm and not 297x210mm. What should be the DPI for width around 1300? Quick [calculation](https://www.pixelcalculator.com/?round=&FORM=1&DP=1&FA=&lang=en&mm1=297&mm2=210&dpi1=157&sub1=%20calculate%20#a1) - DPI = 157, width = 1298px, height = 1836px. Try it out:

```
gen_flow_layout_pdf("3.pdf", 1298, 1836, images, resolution=157)
```

Result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ehhs9oowe8og7r/3.pdf?dl=0

Not good, we need to spread the grid vertically. Play around with `my` (which should be pretty big for this layout to work, around `(1836 - 101*7) / 8 = 141`) argument gets:

```
gen_flow_layout_pdf("4.pdf", 1298, 1836, images, mx=30, my=141, resolution=157)
```

And this gives you the 7x2 layout: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ls2edsvr42bz4vp/4.pdf?dl=0

Do the calculations for other layouts if you want or better write a code that does it. Same principle.

Comment: Hi Yuri! Thanks for answering, I tried the code but can you please explain the code and it's variable such that I can make changes like increase the distance between barcodes vertically and horizontally and change the margins ?

Comment: I added some more comments have a look

Comment: Hi Yuri! I have been struggling since yesterday to make it a 7x2 grid and tried every changes in width and height and failed.. My image pixel is ` barcode = get_barcode(value=i, width=600)`, so how can I set `gen_flow_layout_pdf(r'example2.pdf', 1300, 1500, img, resolution=300)` such that 7x2 is created ? Currently I have 15 Images, for a better understanding I have attached a drive link of images. Please Help!

Comment: Also `mx` and `my` doesn't seem to have any impact on the pdf created, how do they work ?

Comment: See the edit. I explained the principle. This principle can also be easily scripted, if you need to, I suggest you do it for some practice, it never hurts.